# Where can I find the Windows 95 Startup Sound transcribed into music notation or MIDI?

Tags: midi, windows, sound-effects

Not sure if this is the right spot for this, but I know how to get the Windows 95 startup sound as a WAV, but is there a MIDI anywhere? Or do I have to sit at my piano and try to recreate it (as it is one note at a time)

Comment: Can you remind us of which startup sound you're referring to?  It's been awhile.  Can you link to a WAV?  If it's the one I'm thinking of, it should be quick to recreate it.

Comment: @Brad The dun daloun dun dun dun one :) I'll post the link when I get to my computer

Comment: Yep, that's the one I'm thinking of.  I'd just sit down at a keyboard and spend a minute working it out.

Comment: @Brad http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miZHa7ZC6Z0

Comment: In retrospect, it almost sounds like they slowed down a sample of chimes.

Comment: Slightly relevant, [Brian Eno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Eno) made the [Win95 startup sound](http://musicthing.blogspot.com/2005/05/tiny-music-makers-pt-2-microsoft-sound.html).

Comment: Not at all what you're looking for, but I'm sure a few of you will get a kick out of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4skgihJHQ5M

Comment: We used to start our gigs with a piece based on this and the error noises you used to get, along with a simulated computer fail and explosions. Will have to see if I can find a recording :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that was fun!

It's actually a pretty complex piece of synthesizer work--the link ObscureRobot posted in the comments sheds some light on this.

Since the music isn't exactly metered, I didn't bother to attempt to quantify that in transcription (I didn't bother to typeset it either, that would've been more trouble than it's worth). So, I used spatial notation with some relative rhythms notated.

Every instrument is bathed in reverb and tends to 'ping' on the attack with a long decay. I hear four different voices: the "bell" synth that dominates the first few seconds, the piano that enters afterwards, a string-like synth, and a round bass-ish timbre.

I think this sound's inception may be somewhat similar to that of the THX sound--very much dependent on the individual pieces of equipment used to create it, all of which are antiques nowadays. You'd have to ask Brian Eno in order to get much deeper than this--and he probably wan't working in notation in the first place.

[image: Transcription of the Windows 95 Startup Chime]

Comment: If anyone is wondering, there are no double sharps--that G is just regular G#. The scaling made it a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, one last thing I forgot to mention: I lowered the tuning by about 45 cents to match up against A440. Not sure if the sharpness was in the original or only in that recording you supplied.

Comment: The [THX Deep Note](http://www.earslap.com/instruction/recreating-the-thx-deep-note) was done with a C program driving CSound, a very different process from the way that Brian Eno usually works. [Geeta](http://www.theoriginalsoundtrack.com/) [Dayal](http://www.wired.com/underwire/author/geeta_dayal/)'s book [Another Green World](http://www.amazon.com/Brian-Enos-Another-Green-World/dp/0826427863) provides a lot of insight into Eno's studio process.

Comment: I actually knew that about Deep Note--I was drawing the comparison between them both being difficult to fully recreate at present day (deep note because it was actually randomized in the first place)--unless you're saying Eno used a setup that can be easily replicated nowadays?

Comment: In interviews, Eno often claims that he isn't a gear junkie. He also doesn't seem to be technical enough to go the CSound route. He is known for his use and mastery of the Yamaha DX7 and a fondness for Eventide FX units. I'd guess that the sound comes from a DX7 and a rompler sent through an H3000, possibly bounced to tape a few times. Today, I'd use FM8 and Kontakt, and then send them through some Valhalla DSP plugins.

Comment: Unless you happen to have an Eventide and an analog tape studio handy. Then go dive into Geeta's book and grab an Oblique Strategies deck and don't leave the studio for a week.

He is also known for his use of the EMS Synthi, but I don't hear anything like a Synthi sound in the Win95 bootup.

Comment: What kind of "Strings"?

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's just what I hear it as. It's a dense synth texture with overtones that sound like strings. If you can't pick it out of the audio clip, it's the sound that swells up and peaks right about 4.7 seconds.